# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : this localhost page can’t be found error when running the Web API

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This localhost page can't be found webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5254/

HTTP ERROR 404

[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl6fc.png)

[launchsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UkN0.png)

Comment: the result is expected. what are you expecting be found on that url? you need to add controller name to access the particular api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This localhost page can't be found webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5254/ HTTP ERROR 404

In ASP.NET CORE WebAPI project, it does not configure default route or serve default document for root URL path, which cause above issue.

If you check the code of your API controller, you might find that the routes like below are defined.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
```

or

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

To access specific endpoint, please check the actual route defined on that endpoint, you may need to include `[controller]` and `[action]` info in URL while you make request(s).

For more information about routing, please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis

Answer (score 2):

You should add `/swagger/index.html` to the link:

```
http://localhost:5254/swagger/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

solution: add localhost/swagger,
vscode doesn't show swagger url on startup

Comment: Please clarify the answer. How you have expressed the solution is not meaningful for a beginner

Comment: where did you add localhost/swagger ???